# Using angular filter to pad collection with empty placeholders, getting $digest infinite loop errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

We have a requirement where users must select *n* records from a collection. The UI must display empty placeholders for each of the *n* records until each is filled. To solve this I was attempting to use a filter that would "pad" the selected subset with empty placeholders. However, the filter is causing an infinite $digest cycle and I'm not understanding why or how to resolve it. Anyway, given a requirement of 2 selections, my filter might look something like this...

```javascript
angular
  .module('TestApp', [])
  .filter('selectedFltr', function() {
    return function(items) {
      switch (items.length) {
        case 0:
          // No selections, return two empty placeholders
          return [{}, {}];
        case 1:
          // One selection, return it plus 1 empty placeholder
          return [items[0], {}];
        default:
          // Return all selections
          return items;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<!-- Full collection -->
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" ng-click="item.$selected=true">
  {{item.id}}
</div>

<!-- Selected subset -->
<span ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter:{$selected:true} | selectedFltr">
  {{item.id}}
</span>
```

My example is contrived for simplicity. For example, the filter might accept a length parameter and build the resulting collection dynamically. I realize I could dump all kinds of `ng-if` or `ng-show`/`ng-hide` logic into the view to solve this problem, but this feels a bit cleaner...if I can get it working. If you have a better solution I'm up for suggestions!

[Here's an almost working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yx5poDWpYKLVwzlmI9Pe?p=preview) (plnkr) of what I'm trying to do...

Comment: wat is not working in your example?

Comment: @ZhiliangTakutoXing if you open the browser console you'll see a list of infinite digest loop errors

Comment: Still looking for help with this?

Comment: Yes, @tasseKATT I'd still like to find a solution to this. Seems like it's something that should be pretty straight forward and it feels like a good approach to solving my particular problem. I haven't made any headway though and have fallen back on a hack for now :(